# How to rectify Django Integrity Error while creating a nested serializer?

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, nested, elixir-jason

Got an integrity error
[as shown in job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEbYr.png) 
`

```
class JobSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    company = CompanySerializer(read_only=True)
    skills = SkillSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'max_salary', 'min_salary', 'employment_type', 'max_experience',
                  'min_experience', 'company', 'location', 'industry_type', 'skills']
        model = Job
```

`

Nested Serializer got this error
`
Django Version: 4.1.3
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:
NOT NULL constraint failed: naukriapp_job.company_id
Exception Location: D:\naukri\naukrienv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 357, in execute
Raised during:  naukriapp.views.Jobviewset
Python Executable:  D:\naukri\naukrienv\Scripts\python.exe

`
I need to rectify this integrity error

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your models where you have used a foreign key.

```
jobs = models.ForeignKey(Job, default=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
```

By following the above approach integrity issue will get resolved.